# Is there any way to set Python IDLE's interactive shell indentation width to 2 spaces instead of its default?

Tags: python, shell, python-idle

I'm not asking about `Options > Configure IDLE > Fonts/Tabs > Indentation Width` and setting that to `2`. This only sets the indentation width within a file and not the indentation width for the interactive shell.

**What Python IDLE file do I need to change to get 2-space spacing in the interactive shell?**

I like to code with 2 spaces instead of 4 so not having the interactive shell also indent by the same spacing slows me down when transferring out of shell and into a file for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a solution!!!** *1

### Solution

go to idlelib (/lib/idlelib/) *2
open "pyshell.py"
go to `class PyShell`, `__init__`

there are 3 lines

```py
self.usetabs = True
# indentwidth must be 8 when using tabs.  See note in EditorWindow:
self.indentwidth = 8
```

just change them to

```py
self.usetabs = False
# indentwidth must be 8 when using tabs.  See note in EditorWindow:
self.indentwidth = 4 # you decide, lot of people prefer 2
```

### P.S.

this will result in wierd looks:

```py
>>> def f(x): # calculate x*abs(x)
    if x > 0: # it doesn't look it, but this is indented once
        return x*x # and this twice
    else:
        return -x*x
```

But I think it looks better then 8-spaces-tab indent

### footnotes

*1 I'm working with python 3.8 on windows 10, but this may work elsewhere

*2 depending where python is installed
step 1: find python (to me it is "C:\Programs\Python 3.8")
step 2: from there go to /lib/idlelib/

Comment: Nice! I agree, I think it looks better than 8-space tab indent. It is an interactive prompt after all. It needs the `>>>` prompt. Thanks for identifying the file that needs to be changed! That answers the question (regardless if we are editing the core files).

Answer (score 1):

No, not at present.

Shell currently uses tabs to indent, and tabs are fixed in tk as 8 'spaces'.  I believe at least part of the reason is so that follow-up lines are visually indented in spite of the `>>>` prompt.

I don't like this either.  In the future, I would like to move the prompt into a sidebar so that entered code starts flush left, as in the editor, and can use the same user-set indent as in the editor.